# Discord bot not starting up without error message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.io

When i try to start up my bot via node the program quits again without any errors

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: "nope"
   });
bot.connect();
console.log("hi");

bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    console.log('Connected');
});

bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, event) {
    bot.sendMessage({
        to:channelID,
        message:"user, userID, channelID, message, evt:"+user + userID + channelID+  message+  event
    });
});
```

Comment: did you run `npm install discord.io` beforehand? There is not much for us to help you with if there are no errors or details.

Comment: Add `bot.on("disconnect", console.log);` to your code and see what happens. Got this from [here](https://github.com/izy521/discord.io/issues/282)

Comment: Did more Googling, [here](https://github.com/izy521/discord.io/issues/238) it says to run `npm install woor/discord.io#gateway_v6` since v5 is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the token which was somehow breaking stuff.

My workaround, was by just coping my token from the `./auth.json` and place in it manually inside the client variable. (which was retriving from the file)

before:

```
var client = new Discord.Client({
    token: auth.token,
    autorun: true
});
```

after:

```
var client = new Discord.Client({
    token: "REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_TOKEN",
    autorun: true
});
```